# Comparing Means of 2 Groups of Different Sizes Across Time

Tags: anova, t-test, repeated-measures

I am trying to figure out the correct test to compare two different groups between two-time points.

I will have a baseline data collection of the stress levels of male and female caregivers and a collection 1 year later. How do I analyze these? My hypothesis is that males will experience significantly more benefit (i.e., less stress) than females as a result of the intervention. Of Note, it is estimated that there will be 1/3 the number of male caregivers compared to female caregivers (i.e., 90 Female and 30 Male).

I feel like a between-subjects t-test is appropriate but I really am at a loss.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You would use *independent two-sample t-test*, picking the correct version for unequal sample size and possibly unequal variance. Read the assumptions needed for a t-test in general: The means for which you are performing the test is mean change in stress level for 2 groups.

If your null hypothesis is that one mean is greater than the other, you would perform a one-sided version of the test.

Don't get confused by thinking there is something paired in your experiment design. You are comparing means between groups, it just so happens that the value which you are testing is calculated by subtraction. Similar to e.g. comparing means of gas consumption for a fixed distance, where you would first calculate the consumption by subtracting the amount of fuel at then end from the amount of fuel in the start, and then perform the test.